# jquery checkbox is checked need input entry

Tags: jquery, input, checkbox

I have these inputs and checkbox in a form

```
<input class="validate[minCheckbox[1]] checkbox" id="maxcheck_0" type="checkbox" name="children[]" value="Juliette" />
<input type="text" name="school[]" id="school_0" value="" /><br />
<input class="validate[minCheckbox[1]] checkbox" id="maxcheck_1" type="checkbox" name="children[]" value="Franck" />
<input type="text" name="school[]" id="school_1" value="" /><br />
<input class="validate[minCheckbox[1]] checkbox" id="maxcheck_2" type="checkbox" name="children[]" value="Lisa" />
<input type="text" name="school[]" id="school_2" value="" />
```

and this jquery to bind the checkbox click

```
    $('input[type=checkbox]').bind('click',function() {
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        $('#school_0').attr('class', 'validate[required]');
        //$('#school_1').attr('class', 'validate[required]');
        //$('#school_2').attr('class', 'validate[required]');
    } else {
        $('#school_0').removeAttr('class');
        //$('#school_1').removeAttr('class');
        //$('#school_2').removeAttr('class');
    }
});
```

How can I add a class attribute to any input related to its checkbox ?

Comment: Sorry my english is not very good ! related = associated (first checkbox with first input, second checkbox with second input, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all your checkboxes are have ids formated like this "maxcheck_" + some integer and all the associated textboxes are associated according to the integer listed in the checkboxes id.  Then you can:

Get the id of the clicked checkbox.  `split()` that string at the `_` and access the value in the 2nd position of the array.  Using the value from the second position of the array you can then add it to the end of "school_" to modify the correct textbox.

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').bind('click',function() {
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        var idnum = (($(this).attr("id")).split("_"))[1];
        $('#school_ ' + idnum).addClass('validate[required]');
    } else {
        $('#school_' + idnum).removeClass('validate[required]');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the text input is always the next element after the checkbox the this should work:

```
$(this).next("input").addClass("myclass");
```

Answer (score 0):

add

data-id attribute to checkboxes and retreive it/them whenever you want with

```
$(this).attr('data-id');
```

Comment: Well my page is not html5 and I need it valid without data-id ;-(

Answer (score 0):

```
    $('#school_0').addClass('validate[required]');
```